# Common BarButtonItems on NavigationBar

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have 10 `ViewController` which have `NavigationBar` and each `VC` have same 3 Barbutton items (1 on left and 2 on right). Right now I am adding same buttons in each of `ViewController`, so I have duplicated code in 10 controllers for same bar button items.

What will be the correct approach for such scenario. I have thought about using `UIViewController` as Base and add these `BarButtonItem` on `NavigationBar`, but with that path I have issue, as I am using `Coordinator` for navigations, and each of those 3 `BarButtonItem` navigate to other screens. Likewise i tried `UIViewController` extension as well, but still navigation problem is there.

Answer (score 1):

**Objective C**

Declare these methods in one common class, I have `Utilities.h`.

```
+ (NSArray *)setButtonWithTitle:(NSString *)title target:(id)target action:(SEL)action;
+ (NSArray *)setButtonWithImage:(NSString *)imgName target:(id)target action:(SEL)action;
+ (NSArray *)setTwoButtonWithTarget:(id)target action1:(SEL)action1 image1:(NSString *)imgName1 action2:(SEL)action2 image2:(NSString *)imgName2;
```

Then define those methods in respective files. As I have `Utilities.m`.

```
+ (NSArray *)setButtonWithTitle:(NSString *)title target:(id)target action:(SEL)action {

     UIBarButtonItem *negativeSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace target:nil action:nil];
     negativeSpace.width = -10;
     UIBarButtonItem *textBarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:title style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:target action:action];

     NSArray *arrBarItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:negativeSpace, textBarButton, nil];
     return arrBarItems;
}

+ (NSArray *)setButtonWithImage:(NSString *)imgName target:(id)target action:(SEL)action {

     UIBarButtonItem *negativeSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace target:nil action:nil];
    negativeSpace.width = -5;
     UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:imgName] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:target action:action];

    NSArray *arrBarItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:negativeSpace, backButton, nil];
     return arrBarItems;
}

+ (NSArray *)setTwoButtonWithTarget:(id)target action1:(SEL)action1 image1:(NSString *)imgName1 action2:(SEL)action2 image2:(NSString *)imgName2 {

     UIBarButtonItem *negativeSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace target:nil action:nil];
    negativeSpace.width = -5;

     UIBarButtonItem *barButton1 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:imgName1] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:target action:action1];
    UIBarButtonItem *barButton2 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:imgName2] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:target action:action2];

     NSArray *arrBarItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:negativeSpace, barButton2, barButton1, nil];
    return arrBarItems;
}
```

Tn above methods if you need more customisation to button, like bgcolor, titlecolor, etc. Then use `UIButton` and use it with barbuttonitem.

Now, in every ViewController, you just have to put only two lines, one for left button and one for right buttons.

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = [Utilities setButtonWithImage:@"ic_back" target:self action:@selector(goBackToPreviousView:)];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [Utilities setTwoButtonWithTarget:self action1:@selector(showSearchBar:) image1:@"ic_search" action2:@selector(showSortFilters:) image2:@"ic_sort"];
```

**Swift**

```
class Utilities {

    class func setButtonWith(title:String, target:Any, action:Selector) -> [UIBarButtonItem] {

        let negativeSpace = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonItem.SystemItem.fixedSpace, target:nil, action:nil)
        negativeSpace.width = -10;
        let textBarButton = UIBarButtonItem(title:title, style:UIBarButtonItem.Style.plain, target:target, action:action)

        let arrBarItems = [negativeSpace, textBarButton]
        return arrBarItems
    }

    class func setButtonWith(imgName: String, target:Any, action:Selector) -> [UIBarButtonItem] {

        let negativeSpace = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonItem.SystemItem.fixedSpace, target:nil, action:nil)
        negativeSpace.width = -5;
        let backButton = UIBarButtonItem(image:UIImage(named:imgName), style:UIBarButtonItem.Style.plain, target:target, action:action)

        let arrBarItems = [negativeSpace, backButton]
        return arrBarItems
    }

    class func setTwoButtonWith(target:Any, action1:Selector, imgName1:String, action2:Selector, imgName2:String)  -> [UIBarButtonItem] {

        let negativeSpace = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonItem.SystemItem.fixedSpace, target:nil, action:nil)
        negativeSpace.width = -5;

        let barButton1 = UIBarButtonItem(image:UIImage(named:imgName1), style:UIBarButtonItem.Style.plain, target:target, action:action1)
        let barButton2 = UIBarButtonItem(image:UIImage(named:imgName2), style:UIBarButtonItem.Style.plain, target:target, action:action2)

        let arrBarItems = [negativeSpace, barButton2, barButton1]
        return arrBarItems
    }
}
```

Wherever you need, just call it like :

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = Utilities.setButtonWith(imgName: "ic_back", target: self, action: #selector(goBackToPreviousView))
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = Utilities.setTwoButtonWith(target: self, action1: #selector(showSearchBar), imgName1: "ic_search", action2: #selector(showSortFilters), imgName2:
```

Comment: Let me convert code in swift. Meanwhile please add `swift` tag in question.

Comment: Thanks but a question, why dont you created an Extension of UIViewController?

Comment: Ohh man, You can create extension of `UIViewController` as well, as per your requirement. I have created it in one common class, because there are other utilities in that and I am using that file in all of my applications.

Comment: on another thought i think this solution is not feasible for me. Because if i implement it that way i ll have duplicate code for navigation in all 10 controllers. which again doesn't make sense.